# Show that the language L = {< M1 > | M1 is a Turing machine that accepts 0} is Turing recognizable

Tags: turing-machines

Show that the language L = {< M1 > | M1 is a Turing machine that accepts 0} is Turing recognizable. I was told by my professor to go about this proof by giving an informal description of a Turing Machine 'V' that would accept 'M1' if and only if 'M1' was a Turing Machine that accepts 0.

Below I have the informal description I gave for the Turing Machine 'V'. I wanted to know if my description accurately depicts the Turing Machine 'V' and therefore proves that the language  'L' is Turing recognizable. Any feedback would be appreciated.

“V On input M1 where M1 is a Turing Machine

i = 1, stop = false;

While (stop==false){

Simulate i steps of M1 on 0

If the simulation enters an accepting state, stop = true. else i=i+1

}

accept.”